# Binary Files in C: Using fread function and an nlogn sorting issue

Tags: c, string, binary, binaryfiles

I'd really like your help with the following problem.

I need to read **N** integers (in binary format) from two **two binary files**, and to write to another output file all the common integers(again in a binary format) in **O(nlogn)** time.

Here's a sketch of what I want to do:

1-I know that I can't use `fscanf` with `%d`, since these are not text files, but since I know that there are N numbers in each file, I want to run in a 'for' loop N times and

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    fread(&int1, 4, 1, file1);
    fread(&int2, 4, 1, file2);
    arr1[i]=int1;
    arr2[i]=int2;
}
```

Where `arr1`, `arr2` are int arrays of N size each, Is this correct? If I know that there are N integers where every integer represented by 4 bits, I would finish at the end of the file, Am I?

2- I want to use `qsort` for sorting each array with `nlogn` steps, but then how should I compare between the two with still nlogn steps? I didn't get to any smart way.

Comment: I can help you with second part.    
Sort the 2 arrays individually and then use merge procedure from merge sort to combine them into one sorted array in O(n) time.   
 
qsort(arr1)      ,
qsort(arr2)      ,
  
merge(arr1,arr2)  .  
ping me if you need some help with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, except it will not behave correctly when it reaches end-of-file.  `fread` does not detect EOF until you try to read past the end, so you should test the return value in case it reaches EOF or an error occurs, e.g.:

```
if(fread(..., file1) < 1 ||
   fread(..., file2) < 1)
{
    // Error or EOF occurred
    break;
}
```

You could also just slurp the entire arrays in a single `fread` call instead of looping, since the data is binary:

```
int arr1[20], arr2[20];
if(fread(arr1, sizeof(arr1[0]), 20, file1) < 20 ||
   fread(arr2, sizeof(arr2[0]), 20, file2) < 20)
{
    // Error or early EOF occurred
}
```

For your second question, just place all of the integers into a single flat array.  You can either do this by reading them directly into a single array, or copy them into one array after you've read in all of the data.  Then `qsort` the combined array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I didn't get the second part of the answer. I have two N size arrays of int values.( some value can appear twice in some array). Assume A1, A2. I want to  write to another file all the numbers that appear in both arrays, i.e both files. I can sort the merged array in nlogn, and then what should I do?

Comment: Then use [`fwrite`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) to write the data to the new file.

Comment: But how would I know which integers are common to the two arrays?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part about only wanting to print the common numbers.  In that case, what you want to do is sort each of the two individual arrays.  Create a third array, and do the merge portion of a merge sort of the two input arrays, except discard unequal elements.